# function that does not exist using Node.js

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp

Hello I wanted to be able to use a c code with electron, so I used node api except that when I call the function described in my C code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: server is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Test backend\index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.12.0
```

I can't figure out where this is coming from since my code was working before I got this error.

Here is my code:

index.js :

`const server = require("./build/Release/server");`
`console.log(server(12))`

server.c :

```
#include<node_api.h>

napi_value Server(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info){
    size_t argc=1;
    napi_value args[1];
    int64_t upper_limit;
    int64_t largest_prime;
    napi_value output;

    napi_get_cb_info(env,info,&argc,args,NULL,NULL);

    napi_get_value_int64(env,args[0],&upper_limit);
    largest_prime=upper_limit;
    napi_create_double(env,largest_prime,&output);
    return output;
}

napi_value init(napi_env env, napi_value exports)
{
    napi_value server;
    napi_create_function(env,NULL,0,Server,NULL,&server);

    napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "Server",server);

    return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME,init);
```

binding.gyp :

```
{
    "variables": {
        "openssl_fips" : "0" 
    },
    "targets":[
        {
            "target_name":"server",
            "sources":[
                "server.c"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `server.Server(12)`? After all you are setting a named export `Server`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works. I didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: I have an issue when i try to run `npm run start`. Indeed, The server() function does not work even if the software starts (no errors in the terminal). I have the impression that it may be stucked in the require() function.